# Could not generate emails

Tags: wpf

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->    System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mailrelay'
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,                 GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at  EmailSender.PerformDelivery(IMessage message)
```

Below is my code:

```
    mail = new MailMessage();

      string[] toAddresses = email.To.EmailAddress.Split(new char[] { ';' });
      foreach (string toAddress in toAddresses)
      {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toAddress.Trim()))
          {
              mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
          }
      }

      string[] ccAddresses = email.CcEmail.Split(new char[] { ';' });
      foreach (string ccAddress in ccAddresses)
      {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccAddress.Trim()))
          {
              mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccAddress));
          }
      }

      string[] bccAddresses = email.BccEmail.Split(new char[] { ';' });
      foreach (string bccAddress in bccAddresses)
      {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bccAddress.Trim()))
          {
              mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bccAddress));
          }
      }

      mail.From = new MailAddress(email.From.EmailAddress,email.From.FullName);

      mail.Subject = email.Subject;
      mail.Body = email.Body;

      if (email.Body.Contains("<html>"))
      {
          mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
      }

      if (!email.ExcludeAttachment && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.AttachmentPath))
          mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(email.AttachmentPath));

      client = new SmtpClient();
      client.Host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmtpServer"].ToString();
      client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmtpServer"].ToString() is returning "mailrelay"

Check your AppSettings (normally in web.config), find the SmtpServer setting and change it to a machine name, ip address or domain name that is a mail relay that will accept emails from your app (most mail relays are secured to prevent spammers  using them).

If "mailrelay" does work on your dev machine, ping it and find out what IP address it is resolving to. It needs to resolve to a machine that your other environment can see too. If it's a local test machine, then chances are that a production server in a hosting environment can't access it.

Comment: mailrelay is my Host name when i am working on a sample project am getting the mails. but to the real projects its not working.

Comment: can any one reply please

Comment: Thank you very much its much usefull to me

Comment: I have given my local Server IP Address as my smptserver but exception message is thrown as System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xx.x.xx.xxx:25

Comment: can any one please reply

Comment: Do you actually have a mail server running on the machine? This is a separate piece of software and is not normally installed by default. Your easiest option is to use your ISP's mail server (they normally have one, you'll need to find and use their IP address) or you can install something like https://www.hmailserver.com/